# ios submitting an app takes more than 18 days why apple is that slow and questions about iTunes?

Tags: ios

Yes as I said it takes 18 days for an app to be approved and submited to applestore.

I submited two apps already and they took soo long to appear on appstore.Waiting for review took 10 days and in review took 8 days to pass is it normal guys or apple is not showing importance to me or my country ? Is this means that my updates will take same time ?

Also when I check applestore with an ios 5.1 version iPhone I see that my app is in the new apps list just one day after release and its normal but on itunes and on applestore for ios 6.0 an app which is submitted 5 days ago still don't appear on new apps list.When I check the new apps list with iTunes I can see that appss posted 8 days ago appear as new apps on the list so can we say that the old apple store and new one is updated in diffrent times ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been on the AppStore from the start, and I've had apps take from two days to six weeks to get approved.  It seems that average is a week or two.  Yet, we have no information on what Apple is doing, so there is no way to really respond.  When you want to work marketing into your product release, just ensure you plan at least two weeks ahead, and expect that approval can take some time.  Apple probably is like any other company and has restraints of how many people are currently approving apps, as well as how many apps are being submitted.  There is a chance things are taking longer now, as many apps are getting submitted to work with the new 4" screen on the iPhone 5 and iPod Touch 5th Generation.

EDIT: I am not apologizing for Apple, just looking at the situation from their perspective.  I wish apps would be approved in a faster time-frame.  That won't help the situation any, and it is more realistic to plan that it will take some time.  If it takes less time, great!

Answer (score 1):

It took 9 days for my first app to get to review state, in review it was 2 hours, now I just received information my second app was approved which took 7 days till review and 2 hours later it was approved. I don't think there is anything personal or related to your country regarding apple process they use to review your apps.

About the new app list, I think only apple can give you the right answer for that, otherwise it's just guessing.